# Can I extend a shared docker-compose service twice (multiple times)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-network

I have a maria-db database docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress3,wordpress4"
      MYSQL_USER: mohsin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345678
    volumes:
      - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

networks:
  wordpress_network:
    external: true
    name: wordpress_network

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
```

I am running two wordpress docker-compose files (for testing purposes). I want to connect both of them to the mariadb docker-compose. Both files have similar config:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress3
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress3
    ports:
      - "8083:80"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - wordpress_network
  mariadb:
    extends:
      file: ../mariadb/docker-compose.yml
      service: mariadb

networks:
  wordpress_network:
    name: wordpress_network
    external: true
```

When I run the first wordpress docker-compose, it automatically runs mariadb and connects to it. At the same time, the other instance throws an error saying `mariadb already in use`. **I want it to recognize that mariadb is already running, and connect to the shared instance automatically?**

*Two instances access the same db service type of scenario is required (condition: auto runs db service if down)*

Tried using **extend** and **.env** but doesn't work.

Comment: You can only have one container with a given name in your docker compose project. If you want to have two mariadb instances, give them different names.

Comment: Actually I want the same instance to be used, instead of the second instance trying to create its own (with the extend).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the containers you want to talk to each other are on the same network.

for example:

```
# first/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  first:
    ...
    networks:
      - some-net
networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge


# second/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  second:
    ...
    networks:
      - first_some-net
networks:
  first_some-net:
    external: true
```

Note: Your app’s network is given a name based on the “project name”, which is based on the name of the directory it lives in, in this case a prefix first_ was added

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to resolve that part. The error is particularly due to the `extend` in the two services (extending a common service). The **first** manages to create a mariadb instance for itself. The **second** gives an error saying `mariadb already in use`. Here it should instead try to connect to the mariadb service the **first** application ran.

Comment: You need only one instance for database not more! unless you need more instances for cluster database at this situation your container can access db from defined network.
In other solution you have one docker-compose file with two different container like wordpress and one databse for both.

Comment: The second instance (of wordpress) is trying to create a new db service (using the extend). I want to avoid this when it is already running.

Comment: See following link for your scenario for more information:

https://trobertson.site/hosting-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-database-server-in-docker-compose/

Answer (score 1):

It is not logically correct to create two containers for one db, for maria db you have already created a container in your first file, as your two docker services are running in a single network, you can just connect to it. `mariadb already in use` this means that this container name has already taken in your network, so network has this container already, you can change container name, you don't have to create two containers if you want them to be indentical, just use one! .

#### So the conclusion is

1. if you want to use two docker services in one host, and share single database in between, *(And if it is, then your db access credentials should be the same, which is not in your case)* use [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/), and do not create tow identical containers for single service!.
2. if you want to create two different databases with the same configuration just rename the container name in your second compose file, like `mariadb_new`.
3. if you want to use the same db between two docker services which are located in two separate servers, then do not overwrite networks, just get access to them with public IP and served port.

Comment: Let's say I run wordpress service1, it should auto-start mariadb (if not running). Then by running wordpress service2, it should detect mariadb is already running and connect to it (but this is where the conflict `mariadb already in use` is). Is there a way I can make service2 auto-detect the mariadb and then auto-connect?

Comment: In your second compose file, you needn't create container for mariadb, just remove it, and connect to the one which is already created in your first compose file.